# Showing historic path of river using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, rivers

I am trying to create something similar to the image below for Molonglo River in the ACT using ArcMap with several TIF tiles I have mosaicked together but no luck thus far.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

I am a novice at GIS.

[image: historicflowwithlidar]

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/431616/edit) to include details about the data you have for the river.

Answer (score 1):

Such an image is built from a *time* sequence of data. DEM's tend to be a single time period so you could never build such an image.  Satellite data over a long time period would work, the obvious is Landsat. So you take the same tile location from many years, process (classify) each tile so that you distinguish between the land types water and land (you are capturing the meandering of the river) and then simply add them together and colour as desired.

Here is an example of the R. Indus in Pakistan, some work I did a few years ago. The darker colour indicates pixels where water was present over the 10 years of satellite imagery I had used.

[image: Indus]

Answer (score 1):

This image appears to be a relative (detrended) surface model derived from LiDAR data and then symbolized with a monochromatic color ramp based on the resulting detrended surface's elevation.  The Washington State cartographer Dan Coe has published a how-to using QGIS [here](https://dancoecarto.com/creating-rems-in-qgis-the-idw-method).

[Here is a link](https://dancoecarto.com/) to Dan's webpage for more examples of this stunningly beautiful techique.

If you are an ArcGIS or ArcGIS Pro user you can use the detrending toolboxes available [here](https://github.com/LummiGIS/Detrend-Surface-Models).  Disclaimer: I am the author of the ArcGIS tools.